# Are Lead Fields Static after conversion to Contacts?

Tags: custom-field, leads, contact

I'm currently trying to build a few custom attributes within the Lead object so that the following happens:

1. Year Entered for Job is a text field
2. Years since entering the work field is a number field using a custom formula
3. Career Level is converted based on a range and the number for #2.

I have them all working, but had to use TODAY() in my formula for #2. I'm assuming that this means everyone in my system will slowly trickle down to the most senior career level I have in place as the years go on, but this is not what I want. I would like for that field to remain static after conversion to Contact. My question are as follows:

1. Are Lead Objects Static after Conversion? ie: will my people with "Early" career levels stay at early for the rest of time?
2. If not, is there a better way to write my formula (ie: Not using TODAY() ) to ensure that my career level attribute does not change for each individual as the years go on?

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Formula values are calculated when you query the value from the database. In other words, yes, everyone would eventually become "senior level" over time.

Probably the easiest fix is to use the ConvertedDate field after conversion:

```
BlankValue(ConvertedDate, today())
```

Otherwise, consider using a field that can be set upon conversion, driven by the formula field to fixate the value that was present upon conversion. You can use a workflow rule for this.